# getent group database does not match /etc/group

Tags: linux, groups

I have a GID which is present in the **getent** database but not in **/etc/group** :

```
$ getent group 61876 
earlyoom:x:61876:

$ cat /etc/group | grep earlyoom
$
```

Is it normal or should I worry ? Shouldn't they have matching results ?

*edit : fedora 32*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getent uses nss, not directly the file.
Look at `/etc/nsswitch.conf` on line beginning with `group:`

Comment: I have this line : "group: sss files systemd" in /etc/nsswitch.conf but that does not answer my question : this file is used to tell where getent should search isn't it ? What I am looking for is the reason of the mismatch. Unless I don't understand what you mean.. Which is possible.

Comment: That is the reason. getent search for group with sss first, then files (/etc/group), then systemd. Your group comes from sss or systemd.

Comment: But /etc/group isn't supposed to have ALL groups listed then ? I thought so.

Comment: If all groups was in /etc/group, there was no need for GNU Name Service Switch, which read account data from various places, and /etc/group is only one of them. There are a tons of extensions for nss, for reading account from mysql, ldap, sqlite, etc...